# Add a calculated field to AR model in RoR 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, triggers, rails-activerecord, calculated-columns

I am new to RoR and working on an existing Rails 2 app.  The app reports on a number of metrics, and I need to add a new metric that is a ratio of two of the others.  I'd like to understand the "right" Rails way to do this kind of thing.  But I also want to get it done quickly and with minimal risk to the rest of the code.  I want to extend the reporting, summary, graphing, and aggregation logic on the existing metrics to the new calculated field, without having to re-implement everything in a slightly different way.

1. I could add a field to the DB and install a trigger procedure to maintain it.  This has the advantage of pushing the work into the DB, and allowing me to index the field if necessary, but it consumes another field in the DB, and I don't think I really need an index on the field at the moment.  What would the AR migration look like?
2. I could create a view that calculates the field.  How do I just switch my model to use the new view that has the new field without disrupting the rest of the code?  What does the AR migration look like?
3. I could add the new field into the queries ... SELECT my_table.*, a/b AS ab_ratio FROM my_table ... does this mean I need to examine all of the .find calls on that particular model and change those?  Is there a better way to do it?

It would be very helpful to have some code examples of where and how this kind of thing is implemented and/or documented.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using events on the model to calculate a synthetic value and keeping any business logic/triggers out of the database:

```
class MyRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :update_ratio

private
  def update_ratio
    self.ratio = self.a / self.b
  end
end
```